# Typo3 tx_news eventnews: show enddate and location in list view of tx_news

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am trying to add the enddate and the location to the list view of the news records.
For the location it was quite straight forward `{newsItem.location.title}` but the enddate does not work. I tried all different things like:

```
{newsItem.event_end}
{newsItem.eventEnd}
{f:format.date(date:newsItem.eventEnd.date,format:'%d.%m.%Y')}
```

and `{f:format.date(date:n.eventEnd.date,format:'%d.%m.%Y')}` like in the month view but that gives some weird date.

Comment: you should add the output of all those variants you tried.

Comment: You are right, but the first three gave nothing and the last one copied from the Month view gave the 23.6.2021 instead of 28.07.2022 (which i really can't explain). But you solved it anyway, so thanks agin for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you got weird results as you missed the correct data and the correct formatting.

I assume that `{newsItem.event_end}`results in `0`
`{newsItem.eventEnd}` propably gives you a big number like `1623997520`, which is a unix-timestamp and gives the seconds since "1.1.1970 0:00". this just needs some formatting:

In your formatted try you access `newsItem.eventEnd.date` as data, but that also is not defined.

I prefer the inline format, so it's more obvious which data is shown:
`{newsItem.eventEnd->f:format.date(format:'%d.%m.%Y')}`